# Cannot get password_verify to work (PHP, MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I've set up password_hash in my registration script. Can't figure out how to use password_verify correctly to log into my website.

Screenshot of DB: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8xqm.png

Login Code (says "incorrect login, even when the password is correct):

```
<?php  
    require 'db_connect.php';

    if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `member` WHERE username='$username'";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if (password_verify($_POST['password'],$hashword))
        {
             echo "Correct login";
        }
            else
        {
            echo "incorrect login";
        }
    }
?>
```

Registration Code(Works great, no issues with DB connection either):

```
<?php
    require 'db_connect.php';

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password1 = $_POST['password1'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];

    if($password1 != $password2)
        header('Location: registration.html');
    if(strlen($username) > 25)
        header('Location: registration.html');

    $hashword = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $query = "INSERT INTO member ( username, password, email)
    VALUES ( '$username', '$hashword', '$email');";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    mysql_close();

    header('Location: login.html');
?>
```

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: where does `$hashword` come from? can't see it in your login code other than inside password_verify. You are not fetching any data from your query just counting number of rows

Comment: @Matt Lines 14 - 17 in the registration php file

  $hashword = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    
    $query = "INSERT INTO member ( username, password, email)
    VALUES ( '$username', '$hashword', '$email');";

Comment: @zgrav there are no line numbers so can only guess however... `$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));` ... `$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);` ... `if (password_verify($_POST['password'],$hashword))` between the query and the verify, you do not set `$hashword` anywhere

Comment: @zgrav $hashword is not available in login.php though, you need to fetch the data from the database and use it

Comment: I've added 
     $hasword = $result['password'];

Just underneath 
     $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

And get another error: https://i.imgur.com/F5XH8IX.png

Comment: errror reporting would have helped you here as well as error handling on the query. There are methods for you to find and use on php.net's website.

Comment: note: you're mixing mysql apis here `mysql_close();` you can't do that.

Comment: @zgrav please don't vandalise your question. The moderators will get involved if you continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it looks like you are not checking the `$_POST['password']` with the correct hashword which was inserted into the database.

The variable `$hashword` will have nothing and hence `password_verify` fails.

Fetch the value of password which was stored in the database and store it in `$hashword` variable then use it in the `password_verify` function for it to work as intended.

**Example**

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$hashword =  $row['password'];
```

**Usage**

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$hashword =  $row['password'];

if (password_verify($_POST['password'],$hashword))
{
     echo "Correct login";
}
    else
{
    echo "incorrect login";
}
```

Comment: I've added  

$hasword = $result['password'];   

Just under  

 $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

However now I'm getting a different error: https://i.imgur.com/F5XH8IX.png

Comment: you cannot use the response of `mysqli_query` query directly to fetch the record. Please refer my answer on how to fetch the password from the `$result` variable

Comment: Sadly, I get the same error
https://i.imgur.com/LSLdetI.png

$hasword = $result['password'];  is where it errors out

Comment: Try adding the lines `$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$hashword =  $row['password'];`  and remove the line `$hasword = $result['password'];`

Comment: you did not remove the line `$hasword = $result['password'];` please remove it. Remove the line no 12.

Comment: My mistake!

Now I'm just getting "incorrect login". And I'm 100% sure the login is correct. Tried pasting in the hashed password from the database and the original password, neither worked.

Comment: You should use the original password in your form, not the hashed password. Can you show me your file ? along with the inputs ?

Comment: make sure $result['password'] is what you expect it is, check that the hash in the db is correct (many have had too short varchar fields which truncate the hash)

Comment: Sure, here's everything: https://gist.github.com/Lucas-Crosby/ced3932a734999c5bf4c61f9c8237751

Comment: @JimL the varchar limit is 120, each password is hashed to 60 characters I believe

Comment: what about the input which you are providing in the form ? are you sure it is the same password which was used to generate the hashword and got inserted in the database ?

Comment: The code seems to be correct. Register a new user with a simple password, then use the same password to login, check and revert back if it works.

Comment: Same problem, sadly.

I've also echod hashword to check it matches the database which it does.

Comment: can you show the executed code with the output ? perhaps a screenshot with the echod values

Comment: Yes, it does. Change `$hashword = $row['password'];` to `$hashword = $row[2];` and check

Comment: @RamC although I did upvote your answer, I need to state that you didn't catch the fact that they're mixing different mysql api here, with `mysql_close();` and the sql injection holes. IMHO, the answer should be edited in order to reflect and for future users.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yes, I agree, Shall edit and update the answer.